# Data not displaying correctly in modal

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting two values in two rows like suppose my `{{x.room_type}}` displays A in row one and B in row 2. The `href` toggles a modal which displays additional data about A when I click on the A row and additional data about B when clicked on B row.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="x in roomdata.data">

    <div class="well well-sm" >{{x.room_type}}<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#room_detail" class="pull-right">Room Details</a>
    </div>
    <h5 class="pull-right">{{x.rack_price}}<br>Per room per night</h5>
    <img ng-src="{{room_image}}">

</div>
```

But the modal displays the details of only A when I click on the link on both the rows.

Here's the modal

```
<div class="modal" id="room_detail" ng-repeat="x in roomdata.data">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type = "button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3>{{x.room_type}} - {{current_Hotel.hotel_name}}</h3>
                <a href="" ng-click="show = 'desc'">Descriptions</a>
                <a href="" ng-click="show = 'pictures'">Room Pictures</a>
                <a href="" ng-click="show = 'amenities'">Amenities</a>
                <a href="" ng-click="show = 'others'">Others</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe instead of using raw bootstrap modal, you should use ui-bootstrap's modal?

Comment: Looks like I have to learn that now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append `{{$index}}` to your ID and in order to make it work, add it in `data-toggle` too. Something like this:

```
<div class="modal" id="room_detail{{$index}}" ng-repeat="x in roomdata.data">
```

And, the modal opener would be like,

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#room_detail{{$index}}" ...>
    Room Details
</a>
```

So, now all of the modals have unique IDs which will help us distinguish them.

Here's [**working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/h0o0ku1t/)

Comment: @PushUps glad I could help! :)